# how to check if array contains more then one of the same word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a tagging system, and I cannot figure out how to prevent users from spamming the same tag. My only thought is to add each into an array. And make it not add it again once they click it again, but I cannot figure it out.
If anyone could help that would be great!

here is my code sample:

```
<select multiple="multiple" size="10" id="tag_name">
   <option>apple</option>
   <option>pear</option>
   <option>pineapple</option>
   <option>peach</option>
   <option>strawberry</option>
   <option>raspberry</option>
   <option>cherry</option>
   <option>watermelon</option>
   <option>orange</option>
   <option>banana</option>
   <option>grape</option>
   <option>honeydew</option>
   <option>apricot</option>
</select>
<!-- appended tags wrapper -->
<div class="tags"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var tag_count = 0;
   var tag_array = "";
   $("#tag_name").click(function(){
      var tag = $("#tag_name").val();
      if(!tag == ""){
         tag_array = tag_array+tag+", ";
         tag_count = tag_count+1;
         if(????){
            if(tag_count != 11){
               $(".tags").append("<div style=\"margin: 5px;\" class=\"tag\"><p>"+tag+"</p><a href=\"#\">x</a></div>");
            } else {
               $(".tags").append("<div style=\"margin: 5px;\" class=\"tag\"><p>15 tags already selected!</p><a href=\"#\">x</a></div>");
               $("#tag_name").attr("disabled","disabled");
            }
         }
      }
   });
</script>
```

Comment: i tried that, the user will be adding them one by one into the array, not all at once

Comment: 1) What is `if(????){`? 2) Every time you will reload the page, all the tag will be lost or you registered them in database or somewhere? 3) Every time you add a tag, you create a new div with the tag as content, right? Just make a select with all `.tag` element and check if you already same tag maybe

Comment: Using `set` would be an approach, which is similar to an array, but does only allow one value once. https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will do the job!

```js
var tag_count = 0;
   var tag_array = [];
   $("#tag_name").click(function(){
      var tag = ""+$("#tag_name").val();
       if(!tag == ""){
        if(tag_array.indexOf(tag) < 0){
         tag_array.push(tag);
         tag_count = tag_count+1;
         console.log(tag_array);
            if(tag_count != 11){
               $(".tags").append("<div style=\"margin: 5px;\" class=\"tag\"><p>"+tag+"</p><a href=\"#\">x</a></div>");
            } else {
               $(".tags").append("<div style=\"margin: 5px;\" class=\"tag\"><p>15 tags already selected!</p><a href=\"#\">x</a></div>");
               $("#tag_name").attr("disabled","disabled");
            }
         }else{
              console.log("Alredy Tagged - "+tag);
            }
      }
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple" size="10" id="tag_name">
   <option>apple</option>
   <option>pear</option>
   <option>pineapple</option>
   <option>peach</option>
   <option>strawberry</option>
   <option>raspberry</option>
   <option>cherry</option>
   <option>watermelon</option>
   <option>orange</option>
   <option>banana</option>
   <option>grape</option>
   <option>honeydew</option>
   <option>apricot</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about `String.indexOf()`?

```
if (tag_count != 11 && -1 === tag_array.indexOf(tag)) {
  tag_array += tag + ", ";
  tag_count = ++;
  $(".tags").append("<div style=\"margin: 5px;\" class=\"tag\"><p>" + tag + "</p><a href=\"#\">x</a></div>");
} else {
  ..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve this would be to just build the HTML of `.tags` upon the `change` event of the `select`. Then you can simply rebuild the entire list every time it changes. As an element can then only be selected once, there can be no duplicates. Try this:

```js
$("#tag_name").change(function() {
  var values = $(this).val();
  if (values.length > 10) {
    $('.tags').html('<div class="tag"><p>15 tags already selected!</p><a href="#">x</a></div>');
  } else {
    var tagsHtml = values.map(function(v) {
      return '<div class="tag"><p>' + v + '</p><a href="#">x</a></div>';
    }).join('');
    $('.tags').html(tagsHtml);
  }
});
```

```css
.tag {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple" size="10" id="tag_name">
  <option>apple</option>
  <option>pear</option>
  <option>pineapple</option>
  <option>peach</option>
  <option>strawberry</option>
  <option>raspberry</option>
  <option>cherry</option>
  <option>watermelon</option>
  <option>orange</option>
  <option>banana</option>
  <option>grape</option>
  <option>honeydew</option>
  <option>apricot</option>
</select>

<div class="tags"></div>
```

Note the use of `'` as the outer string delimiter. This avoids the requirement to use the ugly escape character for inner double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't got an Arrray there, just a string where you concatenate a new value on.

However you could still use `.includes()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

A better option would be to use an array and see if the value your attempting to add exists in it.

So change:

`var tag_array = ""` to `var tag_array = [];`

and

`tag_array = tag_array+tag+", ";` to `tag_array.push(tag)`;

Then you can do `tag_array.includes(tag)` to see if the tag exists in the array. However i would suggest doing that check before you insert the value into the array or it will always be true. [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

If later you need a comma separated string of tags you can do

`tag_array.join(', ');`

Answer (score 0):

You should try using a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) instead of an Array. This way each entry will be unique.

```js
const set1 = new Set(["Apple", "Orange"]);
set1.add("Apple");
console.log(Array.from(set1));
```

Comment: @loelelele020202 Just a hint: Watch out for browser compatibility and potentially add a polyfill. https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i = 0; i< MyArray.length(); i++){
    for(j = 0; j< MyArray.length(); j++){
        if (i != j){
            if(new String(MyArray[i]).valueOf() == new String(MyArray[j]).valueOf()){
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you know they are strings, then there's no need to check for type.(`MyArray[i]) == MyArray[j])`)